# How to setup Laravel's Eloquent relationship in joining tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm confused of how can I setup Laravel's Eloquent relationship, so that I get to display information from other table.

I have 3 tables:

1.tblBill

```
 fields: id, title, total.
```

2.tblBillContent

```
 fields: id, BillId, ItemId, qty, price
```

3.tblItemInfo

```
fields: id, itemName
```

I want to display on my table the following data. VIEW:

```
id|  itemName | qty | price | total | bill Id
 1   itemNo1     33    10     330       1
 2   itemNo2     20    11     220       1
```

As of now I'm just using a normal Eloquent query:

```
 $id = 1;
 $items = BillContent::where('billId','=',$id)->get();
```

Result:

```
id|  itemName | qty | price | total | bill Id
 1    2(itemID)  33    10     330       1
 2    3(itemID)  20    11     220       1
```

How can I replace `itemID` into `itemName` which will I get from the `tblItemInfo` field? How am I going to set up and then run a query? I can get the expected result if I'll just use the normal query builder. But I want to know how to be able to do this using Eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's really easy, the thing is you have to tell Eloquent how to setup the relations. In your models (you have models right?) add related columns to each other like this;

```
// Bills
public function rows() {
    return $this->hasMany('BillContents', 'bill_id');
}

// Items
public function bills() {
    return $this->hasMany('BillContents', 'item_id');
}

// BillContent
public function item() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Items', 'item_id');
}

public function bill() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Bills', 'bill_id');
}
```

When you are querying the relations, let's say you want to dump a bill's content;

```
// Controller Side
$bill = Bills::find($id);

// Blade Template Side
@foreach ($bill->rows as $row) // See how we used ->items here?
    <tr>
        <td>{{$row->item->name}}</td> <!-- See how we used $row->item here? -->
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Let's say we are looking at an item and we want to see in which bills we have used it;

```
// Controller Side
$item = Items::find($id);

// Blade Template Side
@foreach ($item->bills as $bill) // See how we used ->bills here?
    <tr>
        <td>{{$bill->id}}</td> <!-- See how we used $bill here? -->
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I can create many more examples but this subject is deeply explained in the Laravel documentation, I think you should go over it once more.

Comment: thank you so much for your code @Omer it was really heplful Ill be using you answer as a reference on my next model setup, but I dont get any value with the `$item->itemName` on the view, the `itemName` field was from `tblItemInfo`  I tried to `dd($bill->items)` and it still giving me the same result as `BillContent::where('billId','=',$id)->get();` I still can't display the ItemName text. I applied all the relationship setup from above :) ..

Comment: I have changed the relation names to make it more clear, I think it should work just OK now. The relations can be extended through each other as you can see, just use the other relations name and column name like `$row->item->name`. Hope this fixes this problem, and if you found the answer useful can you mark it as correct please ;)